# Fragment Bundle

Tags: java, android

Please Help me!
What I'm doing wrong?

in Fragment1

```
@Override
public static Fragment1 newInstance(String param) {
    Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key","value");
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString("key");

    }
}

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    textview.setText(mParam1)

    return v
```

in Activity onCreate

```
Fragment1.newInstance("text");
```

and in the end i have null in mParam1

Why?

Comment: You are setting the bundle for the fragment not the activity. What are you trying to achieve here? post more code

Comment: Can you add @Override annotation in your Fragment oncreate, maybe the Fragment dont recognize this method, also you add a Log.d("something",mparam1"); to check in console

Comment: @Override annotation is there

Comment: Im trying to send String from Activity to fragment with Bundle

Comment: Is your app crashing because of the null value? Also, can you post code from your main activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe your mParam1 is null. I think your textview is null because you haven't referenced it. You need to give it a reference to the textview in the layout.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);


    TextView textview = v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textview.setText(mParam1);

return v;

}
```

Also, you need to change `args.putString("key", "value")` to `args.putString("key", param)` if you expect to get the string you passed to the new instance and not get "value" set to all your textviews.

Also, make sure you `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and add this to your MainActivity's onCreate:

```
Fragment fragment = Fragment1.newInstance("Text");     

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, null)
            .commit();
```

Where R.id.fragmentContainer is the id of your FrameLayout in your activity_main.xml.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

If you don't have this, your onCreate in your fragment will never get called and will never inflate. I can't think of anything else it can be because your fragment code is fine. So the problem is in your main Activity.

Comment: Thank you. You are definitely prof ). Tell me please - is it possible to send ArrayList object with this Bundle?

Comment: No problem. It is. If you just want to pass primitive types; just type args.putIntArrayList or args.putStringArrayList. If you want to pass your own list of created objects, you should work on that code and post it in a new question. But to get you started, just implement serializable in your class and then pass the list of objects to args.putSerializable and then getArguments().getSerializable(). Just post the link to your new question in these comments and I'll help if you run into any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the args to the Fragment from the parent Activity.

For instance if you use a ViewPager, in the adapter do the following when instantiating :

```
public class ParentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 private class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    fragment.setArguments(args);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("key", "MyString");
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
 } 
}
```